# How to assign value to oracle cursor while iterating

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have Oracle cursor which contains list of employee table records,
which have column values employee_name, salary, city, state where salary is null.
i want to add salary for each employee based on city or state during iteration of cursor.
e.g.

```
if city is X and state is Y salary := 10000   
if city is null and state is Y salary :=2000   
if state is null and city is Z salary :=10001  
This part i don't have any issue
```

I want to populate the cursor which salary during the iteration time.
so once my loop is over I need that cursor with populated salary;
I have tried many things but not able to achieve I am not able to provide any code which I tried.
It will be great if someone can help me on it.
Or it will be great i can have new cursor and can assign the value when iterating the first one.

Code which I tried

```
for EMPLOYEE_RECORD in EMPLOYEE_RECORD_CUR (COUNTRY_CODE)
  LOOP
      --update salary based on if else 
      EMPLOYEE_RECORD.SALARY:=45454464646;        

  end loop;

for EMPLOYEE_RECORD in EMPLOYEE_RECORD_CUR (COUNTRY_CODE)
  LOOP

     --checking whether salary has been populated or not 
     -- i know this is wrong approach but need help on it
     dbms_output.put_line( EMPLOYEE_RECORD.SALARY);

  end LOOP;
```

Comment: Update the code which I tried

Comment: Yeah I am looking for alternate solution like new values i want to assign to new empty cursor with employee name. Is it possible??

Comment: Are you trying to update your table?  If so, use an `UPDATE` statement instead of a looping through a cursor.

Comment: No actually I am not updating table.It should be in memory

Comment: Actually, the problem is, the scope of the variable is gone after the LOOP.. Your variable usage in second loop will actually be a new local variable. Only way around could be creating a VARRAY/Nested table in PL/SQL and create a copy, and it need the columns to be pre-defined.

Comment: Your problem statement is rather unclear.  A cursor is a pointer to a program-- a compiled SQL statement.  A cursor does not contain rows-- you can fetch rows from a cursor by asking the cursor to execute the program to find the next result.  A cursor doesn't (generally) materialize the entire result set in memory at any point.  A cursor is also a read-only structure.  You can't modify the data that the cursor will return once it is open, you can only fetch from it.  Do you potentially want to include a `CASE` statement in your projection (the `SELECT` list)?

Comment: You can use case statement or decode within the select statement for such operation..

Comment: I am happy with solution provided by @Vance as answer , and the same i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using oracle collections, in your case, you need to have a collection(array) of records. To do it, refer to the ff codes.Put this on your declaration part:

```
       TYPE myrecordtype is RECORD(employee_name VARCHAR2(32767), 
                                   salary NUMBER, 
                                   city VARCHAR2(32767), 
                                   state VARCHAR2(32767));  
       TYPE collectiontype is table of myrecordtype index by varchar2(32767);
       mycollection collectiontype;
```

then inside your loop, add the following:

```
         mycollection(EMPLOYEE_RECORD.employee_name).salary := --number based on your salary computation;
         mycollection(EMPLOYEE_RECORD.employee_name).city := EMPLOYEE_RECORD.city;
         mycollection(EMPLOYEE_RECORD.employee_name).employee_name := EMPLOYEE_RECORD.employee_name;
         mycollection(EMPLOYEE_RECORD.employee_name).state := EMPLOYEE_RECORD.state;
```

then outside that loop, you can refer to the salary on that array based on the employee name(in other words, you can "query" that collection/array based on employee_names). It goes like this:

```
         mycollection(employee_name).salary;
```

or if you want to loop through the collection, you can do this:

```
         for EMPLOYEE_RECORD in EMPLOYEE_RECORD_CUR 
          loop
         dbms_output.put_line(mycollection(EMPLOYEE_RECORD.employee_name).salary);
         end loop;
```

Comment: Thanks @Vance I was looking for exactly same which you mentioned.